# How to speed up google map cluster?, I have 3k markers its taking upto 8 seconds to display the result in Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Want to speed up my google map faster. This may be a duplicate question but I cant find proper solution.

I am using google map in my application, It is taking long time to load markers.

Please advice how to optimize the code?.

Here is my code

```html
var allmarkers = dynamicMarkers.map(function(location, i) {
    if (location.Latitude != "") {
        var icon = iconBlue;
        if (mapZoomed == 0) {
            bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(location.Latitude, location.Longitude));
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        mText = kFormatter(location.PriceCurrentForStatus);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.Latitude, location.Longitude),
            icon: icon,
            label: {
                color: '#fff',
                fontSize: '11px',
                text: mText
            }
        });
        marker.location = location;
        // process multiple info windows
        (function(marker, i) {
            // add click event
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseurl + "/home-search/map/infowindow/" + marker.location.id,
                    data: {},
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        infoWin.setContent(data.htmlContent);
                    }
                });
                content = loaderContent;
                infoWin.setContent(content);
                infoWin.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, i);
        markers.push(marker);
        markerMap[location.ListingID] = marker;
        console.log("End");
        return marker;
    }

});
var mcOptions = {
    styles: clusterStyles,
};
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, allmarkers, mcOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    //
    //map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
    map.setCenter(cluster.getCenter());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it takes long from a database, consider saving markers into xml file as a cache.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).